# UiTextView text to separate UITextField's

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can the text in my `UITextView` be moved to individual `UITextFields`. For example if i have 5 lines of text in the textview i want that to move to 5 UITextFields allocated for each line. I have at the moment been able to populate a `UITableView` with the information however it would be easier for what i need to do if it were moved to TextFields instead.

Comment: I think the textview string will have \n for each line. Scan for the \n character and divide the string accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
   NSArray  *subStrings = [myTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
   textField1.text=subStrings[0];
   textField2.text=subStrings[1];
```

If your textView doens't have any \n characters, then you need to do some more bit of work in getting the textview text based on lines.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //set the textView in storyboard or you can do it here:
   textView.text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";

    //Initialise your array     
    yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
unsigned numberOfLines, index, numberOfGlyphs =
[layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
NSRange lineRange;
for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++){
    (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                           effectiveRange:&lineRange];
    index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    NSString *lineText= [textView.text substringWithRange:lineRange];
    [yourArray addObject:lineText];
}
textField1.text=yourArray[0];
textField2.text=yourArray[1];

}
```

This code assumes you have a reference to a `textView` configured with a *layout manager*, text storage, and *text container*. The `textView` returns a reference to the *layout manager*, which then returns the number of *glyphs* for all the characters in its associated text storage, performing *glyph* generation if necessary. The for loop then begins laying out the text and counting the resulting line fragments. The `NSLayoutManager` method `lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange:` forces layout of the line containing the *glyph* at the index passed to it.

The method returns the rectangle occupied by the *line fragment* (here ignored) and, by reference, the range of the glyphs in the line after layout. After the method calculates a line, the `NSMaxRangefunction` returns the index one greater than the maximum value in the range, that is, the index of the first glyph in the next line. The `numberOfLines` variable increments, and the for loop repeats, until index is greater than the number of glyphs in the text, at which point `numberOfLines` contains the number of lines resulting from the layout process, as defined by word wrapping.

For more [info.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

and then you can do

```
    textField1.text=yourArray[0];
    textField2.text=yourArray[1];
```

For the first iteration, the string lineText will have the first line of your textview, and for the second iteration, it will have the second line of your textView.

Comment: Nope, That just crashes for some reason

Comment: then your textview may not have the \n characters. IS substrings nil ?

Comment: What do you mean is substrings nil?

Comment: in the code I posted, subStrings is an array. Pls check if your array is nil or not.

Comment: At the bottom it doesn't say nil it says "[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"

Comment: yes it is becasue there are no \n charcaters in the string. The whole string is considered as one line and the text got wrapped up in the textveiw. I will update my answer accordingly in few mins.

Comment: I just keep getting warnings for [layoutManager numberofGlyphs]; saying implicit conversion loses integer precision and the same error at index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);. Also when i run it nothing happens

Comment: did u tried the exact same code I provided ? double check the data type at the line [layoutManager numberofGlyphs] it should be unsigned.

Comment: try to change unsigned to int. It is strange that I didn't had that warning on my end.

Comment: Ye it is weird, though it the warning still persists.

Comment: did u run the code ? you can ignore that warning. BTW I ran it on xcode 7.2.1

Comment: i changed it to 7.1 and ran the code though nothing changes.

Comment: am i missing something

Comment: as it is a compiler warning, you can run the code. See if the code fails to run. Put a breakpoint and see if you the strings are getting added to the array in the for loop or not.

Comment: @nandamuri - does the layout manager split simply based on the visual line break - as in, it would present different results depending on screen width?

Comment: yes. It does split based on the visual width(screen width).

Comment: Where would i put `textField1.text=yourArray[0];
    textField2.text=yourArray[2];` ?

Comment: Also it seems that everything after  `for (numberOfLines = 0 etc..` doesn't seem to run, after i tested it with a breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the help however still no luck.

Comment: try to put a textview with some sample text, and call this code in viewDidAppear.

Comment: in the viewdidload and ill try that now

Comment: Added some sample text in viewDidAppear but the textfields are still empty. can you share your code? maybe i missed something small.

Comment: is the array loaded with the strings from textview ? @vype

Comment: yes i just wrote textview.text = @"Hello"; which loads up fine when i run the app.

Comment: can you make a test project with some text fields and textviews and send to me ? I will try to look at the issue.

Comment: Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Your test project worked fine. There are two issues in your code. 1. You didn;t initialised your array. 2. You didnt include the super call for the view DidAppear.

Comment: yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
seems to be crashing the app now and the log says Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107046/discussion-between-teja-nandamuri-and-vype).