# TextView to TextField's

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to save a TextView to multiple TextFields. [I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135416/uitextview-text-to-seperate-uitextfields) but it doesn't work for me at it just seems to crash. I am new to this and am finding it very complicated if anyone has an answer that is simple and easy to implement it would be extremely helpful.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];      
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [myTextView layoutManager];
unsigned numberOfLines, index, numberOfGlyphs =
[layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
NSRange lineRange;
for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++){
    (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                           effectiveRange:&lineRange];
    index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    NSString *lineText= [myTextView.text substringWithRange:lineRange];
    [yourArray addObject:lineText];
}

textField1.text=yourArray[0];
textField2.text=yourArray[1];
}
```

Comment: Please provide error messages, where did you stop and etc.

Comment: Please post some code and error message what you get when app crashing

Comment: what's the crash ? @mitesh

Comment: implicit conversion losses integer percision is the warning i get on [layout manager numberofGlyphs] and index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)

Comment: Is there a simpler way to make this work? Or a way that i can actually understand? Because all i need it to do is put each line in a separate UITextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign strings to a textfield first create a string with the String format and then assign it to the textfield.

```
NSString *yourArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourArray[0]];
textField1.text = yourArray;
```

Comment: I keep getting an error saying terminating app due to uncaught exception.

Comment: @mitesh Can you post the full error log please?

Comment: 2016-03-22 15:44:21.635 testeers[6412:182250] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: @mitesh well your array must be empty.  Index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] means your debugger is trying to access index 1 of array where 0 objects are present.

Comment: The thing is i need it to start empty so i can add in the text when the opens myself.